# Control constraint with include layout by code

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to change constraint by code.

It was working, but doesn't work with include layout.

Please see below code.

I have include in my layout, this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/clMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/color_white">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/album_dp_50"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/black_4E4E4E"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_Finish"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title_bar"/>


<include android:id="@+id/firstPaymentBtnView"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cl_description"
layout="@layout/first_payment_btnview"
>
</include>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my include layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/cl_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.085"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cl_description">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl3Btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/line"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my activity code.

```
 private ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
 private ConstraintLayout firstPaymentBtnView;

 firstPaymentBtnView = findViewById(R.id.firstPaymentBtnView);

 constraintSet.clone(firstPaymentBtnView);
 constraintSet.constrainHeight(R.id.btnPay,0);
 constraintSet.clear(R.id.btnPay);

 constraintSet.connect(R.id.btnPay,ConstraintSet.START,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.END);                         
 constraintSet.connect(R.id.btnPay,ConstraintSet.END,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.END);
 constraintSet.applyTo(firstPaymentBtnView);
```

But if set constraintSet with not include layout is work like this.

```
private ConstraintSet mainConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
private ConstraintLayout mainConstranitLayout;

mainConstranitLayout = findViewById(R.id.clMain);
mainConstraintSet.clone(mainConstranitLayout);
mainConstraintSet.constrainHeight(R.id.title_bar,600);
mainConstraintSet.applyTo(mainConstranitLayout);
```

My screen can be generated normally.

When the user changes the state, one of the buttons needs to change the position.

I have no idea on why doesn't work and and how can I control include layout constraint?

Thanks!

Comment: I found the reason, because my layout has another layer of constraintLayout, which must be handled by the layer inside.....

Answer (score 0):

Try giving layout width and layout height to the included layout